# TeamCity Build Agent: Error registering on the server via URL

Tags: docker, teamcity

I am trying to run and connect a build agent with Docker to my TeamCity server. I execute this command:

```
docker run -it -e SERVER_URL="xxxx:8111" jetbrains/teamcity-agent
```

It tries to set everything up but returns this error:

```
[2019-08-12 11:02:45,218]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - 
Error while asking server for the communication prot
ocols via URL http://xxxx:8111/app/agents/protocols. Will try 
later: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed
out: connect (enable debug to see stacktrace)
[2019-08-12 11:02:45,218]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - 
 Error registering on the server via URL http://xxxx:8111. Will continue repeating connection attempts.
```

Answer (score 6):

Docker link was the solution that helped me:

```
--link  Add link to another container
```

It's not the recommended way and we need to use **Ports**. But this was a quick way to get it running.

My teamcity docker server's name tag  : *teamcity-server-instance*
So, I had to pass this to the --link flag:

```
--link teamcity-server-instance
```

This was my docker run to set up the agent:

```
docker run -d -e SERVER_URL="http://teamcity-server-instance:8111" --link teamcity-server-instance -v <local_volume_mount>:/data/teamcity_agent/conf jetbrains/teamcity-agent
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `docker network` to create a bridge network for running Teamcity server and agent container. By this way you can avoid using `link` as well.

Create Network

```
sudo docker network create teamcity
```

Run TeamCity server

```
sudo docker run -u 0 -it --name teamcity-server-instance -p 8111:8111 --network teamcity jetbrains/teamcity-server
```

Run TeamCity Agent

```
sudo docker run -u 0 -it --name teamcity-agent -e SERVER_URL="http://teamcity-server-instance:8111"  --network teamcity jetbrains/teamcity-agent
```

It will be able to connect with the container name without any issues.

Thanks

[teamcity](/questions/tagged/teamcity) [docker](/questions/tagged/docker)